# What package manager do I use under TermUX (Android Unix/Linux terminal app)

Tags: terminal, android, terminal-emulator

In the old days when Debian, Red Hat, Suse, Caldera, Slackware, and then in the more modern days, with, Ubuntu, there used to be different package managers, that could be used to dowload and install packages (and, perhaps, Unix systems started using these after Linux distributions became popular or developed their own, I don't, exactly, know).

I'm not sure what Ubuntu ended up adopting, as its, package manager. Perhaps one with a graphical innterface (in the old days Linux distributions started with terminal shell command tools)?

Nowadays, on some occasions, I feel, like I need to use TermUX on Android devices.

For instance, I might need to install Git (or, a Git system), on, or within, TermUX.

What package manager would I use, within TermUX (do I have a choice)?

What Unix/Linux command would I issue to get Git.

TermUX is an Android app that emulates a Unix/Linux terminal on Android devices.

Thank you for your answers.

(Please migrate my post to the Android stack exchange if more appropriate there).

Comment: Have you seen https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Package_Management?

Answer (score 0):

use `pkg install git` to install git. See [Package Management @ Termux Wiki](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Package_Management).